# Flash CS5:AS3 - Import swf to play for X seconds?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I need to have a swf load at the beginning, but I don't want to play about the last 3 seconds of the video.

Can someone help me out with a code that would basically have my swf play for "x" seconds?

Heres what I Have so far..  Currently it is set up to play the swf, but subtract "x" seconds from it but for some reason it doesn't seem to work

```
var mySwf:MovieClip;
var reducedTotalFrames:int;

var clipLoader:Loader = new Loader();
clipLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
clipLoader.load(new URLRequest("schoolintro.swf"));

function loadComplete(e:Event):void
{
     mySwf = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content as MovieClip;

     var totalFrameCount:int = mySwf.currentScene.numFrames;

     var secondsToSubtract:int = 3;

     var threeSecondFrameCount:int = (stage.frameRate * secondsToSubtract);

     reducedTotalFrames = totalFrameCount - threeSecondFrameCount;

     stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onRender);

     stage.addChild(mySwf);


}

function onRender(e:Event):void
{
     if(mySwf != null && mySwf.currentFrame >= reducedTotalFrames){
          //This is the end of the SWF with 3 seconds trimmed off. Here we can stop play
          stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onRender);
          mySwf.stop();
          //doSomethingElse();
     }
}
```

Comment: Try some basic debugging, like placing trace statements in the code inside onRender to ensure it's being called, to ensure the mySwf reference is working correctly (for example, tracing out mySwf.currentScene.numFrames, and if its 0, you know you're not referencing your swf properly or the swf is not frame-based(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some basic debugging, like placing trace statements in the code inside onRender to ensure it's being called, to ensure the mySwf reference is working correctly (for example, tracing out mySwf.currentScene.numFrames, and if its 0, you know you're not referencing your swf properly or the swf is not frame-based). If it the SWF is not frame-based, then you're going to have real issues controlling or even doing anything about this since all the animation/action going on inside the loaded SWF is code-based.

Comment: I traced it out and its saying that the swf is only two frames long, when I know for a fact it was a couple hundred.

Comment: i traced the reducedTotalFrames and its giving me -70

Comment: Yeah so there is the issue. Either your SWF is being run VIA code or there are nested movie clips with timeline based animation buried within one of them somewhere. If you coded that SWF within the flash IDE, your code is going to default to PRIVATE or PROTECTED methods, which is going to make it impossible for you to access and override externally. If it's a nested movieclip, you're going to have to either decompile to find out where the timeline is or systematically traverse the display list within the SWF checking the number of frames as you go along.

Comment: Either way, the hassle nearly out-weighs the benefit of trying save time by recycling that old SWF.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would do that though? I made the swf without any code except a stop() at the end.

Comment: Then like I said it's probably a nested movieclip. When you made the swf, did you put a movieclip on the stage with your animation in it?

Comment: nope, it wasn't even that complex.  It was simply a couple hundred frames with a few tweens.

Comment: Perhaps you used motion tweens, and instead of generating a frame-by-frame animation flash generated the actionscript for the tween. Honestly it's something that could go on speculated but the fact is when you trace out the frames, there's only two. Controlling the timeline via the method we've discussed isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change this line from

```
var threeSecondFrameCount:int = (stage.frameRate * secondsToSubtract);
```

to

```
var threeSecondFrameCount:int = (stage.frameRate / secondsToSubtract);
```

not sure is this what you want or not.

Comment: The whole idea is to subtract the number of frames that would occupy a 3 second period of time during playback, which is why the framerate is multiplied by the number of seconds to be reduced, and then that number subtracted from the total number of frames. Should read the whole question. :)

Comment: But I'm stuck on why it doesn't work?  Setting the seconds to subtract interval does nothing at all :[

Comment: See my answer. It's probably at the very least a SWF with some code in it or the display list is built in such a way that the frames being played do not exist on the main timeline, but rather a child of the main timeline. So for example, there is probably a movieclip on the stage in that swf that has the animation inside of it. So when you reference the loaded SWF number of frames, probably says 1 while on that 1 frame in a movieclip with its own nested timline. That is just one scenario there are many many different ways this could be built that makes controlling it externally a real issue.

Comment: thanks Ascension Systems for correctin me and sorry Kudla69 for not read question properly. Ascension Systems have mentioned that if the swf loaded in is not frame-based then the stop() function won't work.